# Subversion Synchronize View in Webstorm

Tags: eclipse, svn, webstorm

I am using **Webstorm** with **Subversion**.

Is it possible to have something like 'synchronise view' in Eclipse?

What I mean is this view :

[image]

In Webstorm it seems you can only blindly update or commit files. It would be good if you could have something where you can incrementally merge your changes like in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

There is no Syncronize view, you need to use Changes/local (shows files changed locally) and Changes/incoming (files changed on server) instead. The first view allows to commit changes, the second - to update